# Redux / Calling dispatch from an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

How can I dispatch an action inside from an action without passing it from the initial call? I just want to remove the `props.dispatch` but I'm not able to get it work.
Already using redux-thunk and I'm new to react. My version works, but it's not the best, I guess.

```
<Files
    onDrop={file => {
        props.dispatch(addFile(props.dispatch, {id: uuidv4(), file}));
    }}
/>
```

actions.js:

```
// addFile
export function addFile(
    dispatch,
    {
        id = uuidv4(),
        file = [],
    } = {}
) {
    doSomething(dispatch, id);
    return {
        type: 'ADD_FILE',
        payload: {
            id,
            file,
        },
    };
}

// doSomething
function doSomething(dispatch, id) {
    dispatch(callOtherAction(id));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapDispatchToProps` and pass it as the second parameter to the connect method. 
Then you will have dispatch method along with your props.

should look something like this:

```
const mapDispathToProps = dispatch => ({
    addFileAction: (file) => addFile(dispatch, file)
})
export default connect(null, mapDispathToProps)(Component);
```

Your addFile action can now pass the dispatch to other actions as well.

Comment: Oh yeah this is awesome, thanks! Finally got it working. `mapDispatchToProps` and `props.addFile({id: uuidv4(), file});` did the trick. Merci!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `redux-thunk`, then your actions might look like this:

```
// actions.js
export function addFile(id = uuidv4(), file = []) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(doSomething(id));

    dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_FILE',
        payload: {
            id,
            file,
        },
    });
  }
}

function doSomething(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(callOtherAction(id));
  }
}

// component.js
import { addFile } from './actions.js';

const YourComponent = ({ addFile }) => <button onClick={() => addFile(id, file)}>Add File</button>;

export default connect(null, { addFile })(YourComponent)
```

There is no need to pass `dispatch` method as an argument.